# change colour of controls in R DT datatable

Tags: javascript, r, datatable, shiny

In R shiny and datatable (DT) would like to change the colour of the control text to blue, as it suggests it can be here:

https://datatables.net/manual/styling/theme-creator

by adjusting the `Control text:` value to `#0000ff` which seems to change the colour of the text for the pagination buttons to be blue as well as the search text etc on the webpage, but i would like this for a shiny app with a `datatable` that has been rendered. Any help would be much appreciated.

Please see below for the example where the text has not had its text colour changed to blue...

```
  library(DT)
  library(shiny)

  ui=shinyUI(

    fluidPage(
      tags$head(tags$style(HTML("table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover {
                                background-color: #9c4242 !important;
                                } "))),
      DT::dataTableOutput("tt")
      )
    )

  server=shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$tt=DT::renderDataTable(
      DT:::datatable(
        head(iris, 50),rownames = FALSE,options = list(dom='ptl',
                                                       initComplete = JS(
                                                         "function(settings, json) {",
                                                         "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#000', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                                         "}")
        ),
        container = tags$table(
          class="compact",
          tags$thead(tags$tr(lapply(colnames(iris), tags$th)))
        )
      ) %>% formatStyle(columns=colnames(iris),color='white',background = 'black',target = 'row')
    )
  })


  shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

Comment: You just need to apply some CSS. If you inspect the page you linked, it changes the following elements `.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate`

Comment: can you show me an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example (only included UI code)

```
ui=shinyUI(

    fluidPage(
        tags$head(tags$style(HTML("table.dataTable.hover tbody tr:hover, table.dataTable.display tbody tr:hover {
                                  background-color: #9c4242 !important;
                                  }
                                  "))),
        tags$style(HTML(".dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_length, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_filter, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_info, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_processing,.dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button, .dataTables_wrapper .dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.disabled {
            color: #0000ff !important;
        }")),
      DT::dataTableOutput("tt")
        )
    )
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this for individual datatables? I have a page with several, and putting this code in any one applies it to all of them

Comment: Really wish this could be handled within programming using the DT library, but this is a huge help for those who don't know CSS very well. Thanks!