# Style the default parts of a DT::Datatable

Tags: r, dt

I would be very interested to know if there is a way to style (change color in particular) the default parts of a DT datatable like `"Show Entries", "Search","Showing to of entries", "Previous" "Next"`

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change colour of controls in R DT datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444317/change-colour-of-controls-in-r-dt-datatable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a lot of questions in a single question....

To change the *"Showing 1 to 10 of 100 entries"*, use the `infoCallback` option. For example:

```
  infoCallback <- c(
    "function(settings, start, end, max, total, pre){",
    "  return 'Showing '+ start +' to '+ end +' of <b>'+ total +'</b> entries';",
    "}"
  )
```

This will print the total number of entries in bold. And put it in the options: `options = list(infoCallback = JS(infoCallback))`. See https://datatables.net/reference/option/infoCallback.

To change "Next" and "Previous", see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51444961/how-can-i-change-the-labels-of-these-buttons-in-dtdatatable-in-r-and-change-co/51447995#51447995).

And [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language) you have a complete description. An example:

```
library(DT) 
datatable(
  mtcars, 
  options = 
    list(language = 
           list(paginate = 
                  list('next'="NEXT PAGE", 
                       previous="PREVIOUS PAGE"), 
                info = "These are entries _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ total entries",
                lengthMenu = "Display _MENU_ entries",
                search = "Search box"
           )
    )
)
```

[image]

You can use some HTML to style, e.g. the colors, for example:

```
library(DT) 
datatable(
  mtcars, 
  options = 
    list(language = 
           list(paginate = 
                  list('next'="NEXT PAGE", 
                       previous="PREVIOUS PAGE"), 
                info = "These are entries _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ total entries",
                lengthMenu = "Display _MENU_ entries",
                search = "<span style='color:red'>Search box</span>"
           )
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: oh cool answer .is it possible to change also the color of the page numbers between 'PREVIOUS PAGE' and 'NEXT PAGE'?

Comment: @firmo23 That should be doable inside shiny, by setting the CSS properties.